# Can i quit my current job and work as freelancer on EU Bluecard in France

Tags: france, blue-card, freelance

I am holding a valid EU Bluecard since 2 years and working for a France based company.
Now I am exploring options towards taking up freelance jobs by quitting my current full time job.
I have searched many groups and France Tax website but no where mentioned about Bluecard holders+Freelance jobs

1. Could some one please confirm can I take up the freelance jobs in EU?
2. If so, what are the tax implications?

Comment: What gave you the impression this was possible?

Comment: Because I see that the EU Bluecard has many benefits and thought this is also might be possible. So, as per your comment I take the answer as "impossible" to do. Thanks @Relaxed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.
An EU Blue Card gives highly-qualified workers from outside the EU the right to live and work in an EU country, provided they have higher professional qualifications, such as a university degree, and an employment contract or a binding job offer with a high salary compared to the average in the EU country where the job is.  You must work as a paid employee - the EU Blue Card does not apply to self-employed work or entrepreneurs.

Source: https://ec.europa.eu/immigration/blue-card/essential-information_en

Comment: Thank you for your response and clarification. Indeed it seems i can't take up the freelance jobs with the EU bluecard. Need to register a company and that has many clauses depending on the type of company and work.